# Server 2008 R2 - Migrating SYSVOL to DFSR stuck at Migration has not yet reached

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Scenario:

DC01 - Windows 2008 R2 - DC

DC02 - Windows 2003 - DC

I wanted to migrate active directory to 2016 server. First I removed the 2003 base DC successfully without any error messages, then cleaned all entries from the 2008 DC/DNS, checked all replication status all are ok on DC01 no errors.

Now I started SYSVOL migration to DFSR, after stage 2 , its keep saying

```
C:\>dfsrmig /getmigrationstate

The following Domain Controllers are not in sync with Global state ('Redirected'
):

Domain Controller (Local Migration State) - DC Type
===================================================

20008r2DC ('Preparing') - Primary DC

Migration has not yet reached a consistent state on all Domain Controllers.
State information might be stale due to AD latency.

C:\>
```

I tried this

```
C:\>repadmin /syncall /force /APed
Syncing all NC's held on DC01.
Syncing partition: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=MYDOMAIN
CALLBACK MESSAGE: SyncAll Finished.
SyncAll terminated with no errors.

Syncing partition: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=MYDOMAIN
CALLBACK MESSAGE: SyncAll Finished.
SyncAll terminated with no errors.

Syncing partition: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MYDOMAIN
CALLBACK MESSAGE: SyncAll Finished.
SyncAll terminated with no errors.

Syncing partition: CN=Configuration,DC=MYDOMAIN
CALLBACK MESSAGE: SyncAll Finished.
SyncAll terminated with no errors.

Syncing partition: DC=MYDOMAIN
CALLBACK MESSAGE: SyncAll Finished.
SyncAll terminated with no errors.
```

but server still stucked on the error message.
how can i solve it ? what impact it will have on eh running production dc server?

Comment: If you only have the one Windows 2008 R2 domain controller, what are you replicating with? Also, the Global State is 2 (Redirected), but DC01 has not yet entered the Prepared State (1). How did the Global State get set to Redirected? You should not be in Redirected state if any domain controllers haven't finished the transition to Prepared.

Comment: Ok my2  days were very frustrating, finally I was able to restore DC from veeam, after that system state restore  and all restored fine. Can I migrate from FRS to DFRS on singel server? exampe on 2008 server i have frs, i want to move to 2016 so i should migrate my 2008 to DFRS first?